# CSS variables do not work in media queries of other React components

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries, css-variables

My app.css contain this css variable which is used in my css header component and it works well.

```
:root {
  --fs-subtitle-spartan: 1rem;
}
```

The class that uses it in the header component :

```
.menu__items {
 font-size: var(--fs-subtitle-spartan);
}
```

But when I want to modify the variable in media queries of my header it doesn’t work.

```
@media (width < 48em) {
  :root {
    --fs-subtitle-spartan: 1.5rem;
  }
```

How can I change css variables in media queries of other components ?

It only works if I change the css variable in the media queries of my app.css.

Answer (score 1):

Try `@media (screen and max-width = 768px)` instead of `@media (width < 48em)`. This is because:

- your media query's syntax wasn't correct
- you should always use `px` values in media queries, never `em`, because `px` values are absolute.

Comment: I use the level 4 specification of media queries as follows: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#syntax_improvements_in_level_4
 The syntax works well in my app.css. I tried the basic syntax but it doesn’t work in the component header either. I use the em value for consistency in all browsers because safari does something different if you use rem or pixels compared to other browsers.